# NFT/data insertion transactions in bitcoin (Taproot)

Tags: transactions, taproot, nft

I want to find transactions in Bitcoin which are of data insertion type. The new taproot and scripting feature in Bitcoin allows for NFT data insertion. I am wondering how I can detect these types of transactions.

Thank you

Comment: Does either https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118227/5406, or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/117018/5406 answer your question?

Comment: Please also note that NFTs and data insertion were NOT enabled by Taproot. See for example: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/118242/121614